# How to Add class to all images inside div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Inside div I am dynamically loading inner text and it also contains `img` tags. After rendering dynamically I want to add class to all images present insdie that div.

I have tried this but its not working for me.

`src` of every `img` tag inside div is starting from `data:image`

```
function loadDiv() {

         // loading successfully div elements

          $("img[src*=data:image]").addClass("img-responsive");


     }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either use `''` to enclose the attribute value

```
$("img[src*='data:image']").addClass("img-responsive");
```

or escape the `:`

```
$("img[src*=data\\:image]").addClass("img-responsive");
```

<sub>*Some special characters are used by jQuery filters/selectors; so they need to be escaped to form an expession</sub>

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer for a conditional on the data- attribute

```js
$(function() {
  var img = $('img');
  img.attr('src') === 'data:image' ? img.addClass("img-responsive") : img.addClass("another-class");
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="data:image" />
<img src="data:image" />
<img src="data:image" />
<img src="data:image" />
<img src="data:image" />
<img src="data:image" />
<img src="data:image" />
```